# Community User Deleting Posts with Upvoted Answers

Tags: bug, status-completed, community-user, deleted-users

According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/185951), the Community User (CU) shouldn't have deleted [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24920577/1301972). This action seems incorrect because:

1. As I understand it, the Community User shouldn't be deleting questions with upvoted or accepted answers.
2. According to the Community User's mission statement, this seems like a bug rather than a deliberate algorithmic feature.
3. Duplicate questions are often sign-posts to more canonical questions. Other posts on meta have recommended not deleting them unless they are "broken windows."
4. While it may not have been useful in this case, upvoted answers should probably be merged with the canonical question/answers, rather than being deleted along with the post.

Of *course* I'd like not to have lost rep when my accepted answer was deleted along with the question, but I think this is a broader issue about what the Community User should and should not be doing.

Is the earlier information about when CU deletes questions out of date? If not, why did CU "go rogue" here? More importantly, what should CU do in cases like this in the future?

Comment: Related on Meta.Programmers.SE: [What roomba script went after this question](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6820/what-roomba-script-went-after-this-question) - note that 10k users *can* undelete the question (see [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/235254/213963) for the change that made it so).

Comment: @MartijnPieters nope.  Your duplicate post is one of the roomba scripts.  Having an up voted or accepted answer (as this one was described to be) would have prevented that roomba script from acting on it.  As Anna describes, this was triggered by a user being deleted which has all negatively scored questions deleted along with it (even if there are positively scored answers).

Comment: See also: [A question should not be deleted by the user deletion algorithm if it has upvoted answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote)

Comment: @MichaelT: it appears I misremembered; it was in the context of a rage-unaccept-before-requested-account-deletion. Vote retracted in any case.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The post was deleted because it was negatively scored and *the user* who posted it was deleted at their own request.

See also: [What happens to a question when a user is deleted?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187626/155160)

Comment: What you're saying makes sense, but it's confusing because the post says "deleted by Community♦ 1 hour ago." It's not obvious that the *user* was deleted unless one goes hunting for the user's icon and finds it unclickable.

Comment: @CodeGnome Well, anything deleted by Community is going to have an inherent amount of obscurity as to why it occurred unless you know *all* the possibilities of what can cause it to occur and what signs to look for in order to determine why it occurred. Community is not only used for automated scheduled deletions.

Comment: @animuson Fair enough. I still think it's a UI issue, but perhaps that's separate from the question I originally asked.

Comment: @Adam Could Community autonomously comment with reason for action where possible? Not sure what kind of system it is, but with expert systems it's a good idea to have some sort of rudimentary rational tracking, which usually serves a purpose that applies here: reassuring others that its autonomous actions are rational :) Just a simple string for each potential if/then rule/action pair or whatever drives it, and how to expose that string(through question comment, answer comment, edit note, etc.) would serve this purpose. Of course the devil is in the details.

Comment: @AaronLS In principle, yes. In practice, I don't think it's necessary. It'd work to fine to satisfy a 10k user's (who doesn't know about/doesn't notice the author deletion) curiosity, but beyond that we already have various ways of tracking this that are available to employees and diamond moderators. The vast majority of these posts also tend to have low views. Even the one in this specific case had a grand total of 74 views before it was deleted. All in all, little is lost and there's not much point in creating a potentially large number of comments (depending on the number of posts).

Comment: @animuson Arguably, in this situation the question should be "deleted by owner", since they _did_ request their account deleted...

Comment: @Izkata That would only make sense, though, if the user was eligible to delete the question. There are restrictions that prevent an OP from unilaterally deleting a question. In this very case, the OP would have been prevented from doing so. So that notice wouldn't have made any more sense than the current one. The Community user is meant to complete actions on behalf of the community, which they normally might not be able to do. That's what it's done.

Comment: Some checks should be kept in place to delete a question - Up vote on questions/ Up vote on answers should be considered before deleting the question

Comment: This is getting ridiculous. The following question had a 3-Upvote Answer and was deleted 2 days ago. [C language receive struct in another function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50779356/c-language-receive-struct-in-another-function/50779476#50779476). Why should we spend time providing quality answers if they are just subject to deletion despite being upvoted?

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's an understandable frustration, for sure. I undeleted the question, and will pass your comment along internally.

Comment: Adam raised hell and got this fixed, @David - thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @AdamLear thank you! It just left me shaking my head. When things like this happen, it has a chilling effect on the willingness to help new SO members, with little or no rep, as that is an indication that the question will likely be deleted, even if good effort is put forth on the answer and it is reviewed and upvoted by your peers. Thank you both for your help.

Answer (score 3):

As of July 13th 2018, [we've changed this behavior](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/199860/a-question-should-not-be-deleted-by-the-user-deletion-algorithm-if-it-has-upvote/312594#312594):

> delete a user's posts along with them only when those posts...
>
> - ...score < 0 AND
> - ...are closed OR
> - ...have no answers scoring > 0

Making an exception here for accepted answers doesn't make much sense to me; it loses a good deal of meaning when the asker can no longer participate. Same for duplicates: if neither the question nor its answer has proved themselves useful to others, maintaining them as a signpost is dubious. But this change should suffice to cover the majority of accepted answers which have proved useful to others.